# ToggleButton per Lollipop

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I want my ToggleButton to like like this . [image: Toggle as in Lollipop]

But with this code , it always shows me the older toggle button. [image]

Am running the code in Emulator with API 21 only, Am I missing something here. My code snippet is

```
   <ToggleButton

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: *Am I missing something here* yeah, news from the android's world ... such as appcompat library ...

Answer (score 6):

Found a solution.

Using Android support library. Code snippet is..

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
            android:id="@+id/id_useridview_switch"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:theme="@style/colortoggle"
            />
```

Thanks Selvin, got a clue from ur and on what to search

Answer (score 0):

In this code you just set the width and height of your toggle button!
for Android L toggle button you should use support libraries to achieve that!
google something like these:

***android L Toggle button support libraries***
Also search in [***Github.com***](http://github.com)

Comment: Thanks DEON, your answers helped to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Use Switch instead of toggle button you will get what u need. No need for external libraries